# Why would an HDMI cable show a black screen for 1080p?

Tags: resolution, hdmi, 1080p

I recently installed a 30 foot HDMI cable through my ceiling for a projector set-up in my basement. Prior to installation, the cable worked with my Apple TV to my television. However, after installation the cable only presents a black screen when plugged into my Apple TV.

With a little investigation, I was able to plug my computer into the HDMI cable and got a clear picture when the resolution was set at 720p or 1080i. Setting my computer resolution to 1080p caused a flickering, snowy picture that was not readable.

The cable I purchased was rated for 3D, 4K and audio return so I felt I had purchased a quality cable. My assumption would be that during installation threading the cable through the ceiling may have damaged the cable? Yet it still provides a clear, consistent picture on the 720p and 1080i.

Any ideas to a solution? Or might I need a new cable? I don't want to struggle through the hassle of fishing a new cable through the ceiling if there is a simpler solution. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible you simply damaged the cable when installing it? Are there any sharp bends in the cable now?

Comment: You could try cleaning the connectors with an air duster as a simply cross your fingers and hope fix. If you have been threading it through a ceiling where there will be loads of dust, it is possible you've got some in the connector causing an intermittent connection.

Comment: I suspect dirt/dust/debris as well, even if that's not so obvious to the naked eye.  I always tape the ends when fishing hdmi.  You might want to try a little alcohol if air duster alone doesn't work.

Comment: I'm away from home right now, I did try air dusting, but quickly. Will try a more thorough cleaning of the connectors and pray for the best. I'll update on the status

Answer (score 0):

it also happens what the TV doesn't support the HDMI and the Signal goes out of Range, you simply have to set up your TV on HDMI settings before you plug in the HDMI cable so you can avoid the Black Screen!

Comment: I think you missed the point that it worked as expected before installing in ceiling.